# Build a drivers leaderboard using a defined criteria

Tags: javascript, sorting

I wish to build a drivers leaderboard based on the individuals performance.

```js
driver  = [];
    
    for(n=0; n<=4; n++){
        driver[n]       = new Object();
        driver[n].rank  = n;
        driver[n].name  = "Driver "+n;
        driver[n].pts   = 10;
        driver[n].placings  = new Array();
        for(a=0; a<=4; a++){
            driver[n].placings[n][a]    = 0;
        }
    }
    
    driver[0].placings[0]   = 2;    //  [0] == 1st place;
    driver[0].placings[1]   = 1;    //  [1] == 2nd place;
    driver[0].placings[2]   = 0     //  [2] == 3rd place;
    driver[0].placings[3]   = 1;    //  [3] == 4th place;
    driver[0].placings[4]   = 0;    //  [4] == 5ht place;
    
    driver[1].placings[0]   = 2;
    driver[1].placings[1]   = 0;
    driver[1].placings[2]   = 0
    driver[1].placings[3]   = 1;
    driver[1].placings[4]   = 1;
    
    driver[2].placings[0]   = 1;
    driver[2].placings[1]   = 0;
    driver[2].placings[2]   = 0
    driver[2].placings[3]   = 0;
    driver[2].placings[4]   = 3;
    
    driver[3].placings[0]   = 0;
    driver[3].placings[1]   = 0;
    driver[3].placings[2]   = 3
    driver[3].placings[3]   = 0;
    driver[3].placings[4]   = 1;

    driver[4].placings[0]   = 2;
    driver[4].placings[1]   = 1;
    driver[4].placings[2]   = 0
    driver[4].placings[3]   = 1;
    driver[4].placings[4]   = 0;
    
    // Drivers are ranked according to the number of pts scored - in this example over the season each driver has scored 10pts (driver[n].pts). 
    // If drivers are tied for a position, a countback system is used, with the driver registering the most gp race wins ranked highest (driver[n].placings);
    // If they are tied on race wins, seconds, then third, fourth and fifth places are taken into consideration. 
    // If this cannot split them the lowest rank takes precedence (driver[n].rank);
```

The criteria for the result should be as follows: Drivers are ranked according to the number of pts scored - in this example over the season each driver has scored 10pts (driver[n].pts).

If drivers are tied for a position, a countback system is used, with the driver registering the most gp race wins ranked highest (driver[n].placings);

If they are tied on race wins, seconds, then third, fourth and fifth places are taken into consideration.

If this cannot split them the lowest rank takes precedence (driver[n].rank) - (in this case both driver[0] and driver[4] have identical records - driver[0] would take precedence as he is ranked higher).

If it was purely on points I know how to work this out but adding the additional criteria has foxed me - I initially had the idea of multiplying by 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 on each placing and then sort that number.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple sort conditions and apply the one that returns a non-zero result in according order.

```js
let driver  = [];
    
    for(let n=0; n<=4; n++){
        driver[n]       = new Object();
        driver[n]['rank']  = n;
        driver[n]['name']  = "Driver "+n;
        driver[n]['pts']   = 10;
        driver[n]['placings']  = new Array();
        for(let a=0; a<=4; a++){
            driver[n].placings[a]    = 0;
        }
    }
    
    driver[0].placings[0]   = 2;    //  [0] == 1st place;
    driver[0].placings[1]   = 1;    //  [1] == 2nd place;
    driver[0].placings[2]   = 0     //  [2] == 3rd place;
    driver[0].placings[3]   = 1;    //  [3] == 4th place;
    driver[0].placings[4]   = 0;    //  [4] == 5ht place;
    
    driver[1].placings[0]   = 2;
    driver[1].placings[1]   = 0;
    driver[1].placings[2]   = 0
    driver[1].placings[3]   = 1;
    driver[1].placings[4]   = 1;
    
    driver[2].placings[0]   = 1;
    driver[2].placings[1]   = 0;
    driver[2].placings[2]   = 0
    driver[2].placings[3]   = 0;
    driver[2].placings[4]   = 3;
    
    driver[3].placings[0]   = 0;
    driver[3].placings[1]   = 0;
    driver[3].placings[2]   = 1
    driver[3].placings[3]   = 0;
    driver[3].placings[4]   = 1;

    driver[4].placings[0]   = 2;
    driver[4].placings[1]   = 1;
    driver[4].placings[2]   = 0
    driver[4].placings[3]   = 1;
    driver[4].placings[4]   = 0;
    
    let rankings = driver.sort((a, b) => {

      let points_ranking = b.pts - a.pts !== 0 ? b.pts - a.pts : null
      let places_ranking = [...Array(driver.length).keys()]
                            .map(p => b.placings.filter(e => e === p).length - a.placings.filter(e => e === p).length)
                            .find(e => e !== 0)
      let rank_ranking = a.rank - b.rank !== 0 ? a.rank - b.rank : null
      
      return points_ranking ||  places_ranking || rank_ranking
    })
    
    // Drivers are ranked according to the number of pts scored - in this example over the season each driver has scored 10pts (driver[n].pts). 
    // If drivers are tied for a position, a countback system is used, with the driver registering the most gp race wins ranked highest (driver[n].placings);
    // If they are tied on race wins, seconds, then third, fourth and fifth places are taken into consideration. 
    // If this cannot split them the lowest rank takes precedence (driver[n].rank);
```